# On making a forum-user-hiding script more robust

Tags: javascript

I wrote a forum-user-"banning" javascript as a userscript(attaches itself to each website) in opera that makes undesired users' posts invisible on my computer.

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf("wbsite.com/name.html") != -1) 
{
  Wortliste=['Persona non grata 1','Persona non grata 2'];                       

  TagListe=document.selectNodes("//tr");
    for (var Durchgehen=TagListe.length-1; Durchgehen>=0; Durchgehen--) {
        if (IstVorhanden(TagListe[Durchgehen].innerHTML, Wortliste)) {
            TagListe[Durchgehen].innerHTML = '';
        }
    } 
}

function IstVorhanden(TagListeElement, Wortliste) 
{
  for(var Durchgehen = Wortliste.length - 1; Durchgehen>=0; Durchgehen--) 
  {
    if(TagListeElement.indexOf(Wortliste[Durchgehen]) != -1) 
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

As I understand it, this code goes through each node, checks, whether the node contains the undesired persons name and replaces this area with ''.

This works for

```
<div class = "outside">
  <div class = "inside">Persona non grata 1 
  </div>
  <div class = "text">Undesired text
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class = "outside">
  <div class = "inside">Persona non grata 1   
    <div class = "text">Undesired text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But not with

```
<div class = "outside">
  <div class = "inside">Persona grata: "I disagree with the statement of Persona non grata 1" 
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class = "outside">
  <div class = "inside">Persona grata: [quote="Persona non grata 1"]Some text[/quote] 
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class = "outside">
  <div class = "inside">Persona non grata 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class = "outside2">
  <div class = "text">Text from Persona non grata 1
  </div>
</div>
```

When `TagListe=document.selectNodes("//tr");` is replaced with  `TagListe=document.selectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class,'outside')]");`.

How to make it work with only the first two cases?

Comment: How is this banning users - it simply removes the name from the page?

Comment: @Pointy You understand that this is running on my computer, only?

Comment: @Kami It is banning them *on my computer only*. That is the purpose. Don't get stuck up on the term `ban`, use `invisible` if you will. Also, it does not remove just the name but the whole container the name is in. Which creates the problems mentioned.

Comment: Oh, OK - I wasn't trying to offend, but it's not uncommon around here for people to ask about "security solutions" involving nothing but some JavaScript. (Now that I re-read your first sentences I realize that I completely misunderstood. My apologies.)